# P5 JavaScript for loop nned help of shifting lines

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am having this code

```
   for(var i = 0; i < 5; i+=1)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            image(itemImg, 776 + j * 58, 383 + i * 74);
        }
    }
```

What I have there is image which needs to match spots on screen. So I draw 7 columns and 5 lines as of for loop but what I need is every next line except first line to shift by 58 pixels. How that could be done in for loop or if statement in the loop?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. But what about `image(itemImg, 776 + j*58 + i*58, 383 + i*74);`?

Comment: on attached pic 5 rows of circles and  icons which needs to be put into those circles. every next row shifts 1 circle to right.

hope it makes sense.

thank you  [Pic][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT9M5.png